# Which view am I passing above?

Tags: android

I had a TableLayout with TextViews in each cell:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SopitaActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="50dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.7" >

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="00" 
            android:padding="10dip"/>
        <TextView android:text="01"
            android:padding="10dip" />
        <TextView android:text="02"
            android:padding="10dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="10"
            android:padding="10dip" />
        <TextView android:text="11"
            android:padding="10dip" />
        <TextView android:text="12"
            android:padding="10dip" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="20"
            android:padding="10dip" />
        <TextView android:text="22"
            android:padding="10dip" />
        <TextView android:text="23"
            android:padding="10dip" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to detect which one I´m passing with a long press (or another one).
I´ve tried to assign `OnTouchListener` and `OnLongClickListener` and a tag to each textview, and then detect when they are touched, but not when changed of view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v("CCC", "i:   " + v.getTag());
}
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("DDD", "ii:   " + v.getTag());
    return false;
}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone!

The issue is that in the LogCat only appears the first Textview clicked.
If I do this movement:

[image]

I would like to see in the logcat (for example):

```
ii: 00
ii: 10
ii: 20
```

Comment: what is the issue ?  is the onLongClick event not responding ?  in this case if each textview has a onclicklistener then you dont need a tag since your getting the view itself in onLongclick.   we need more info on your issue

Comment: The issue is that in the LogCat only appears the first Textview clicked.

Answer (score 0):

in each textview add android:onClick="myFunction"

then create a function called myFunction(...) and it will respond to each click.

```
<TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="00" 
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:onClick="myFunction"/>
        <TextView android:text="01"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:onClick="myFunction" />
        <TextView android:text="02"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:onClick="myFunction" />
    </TableRow>


public void myFunction(final View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",2).show();
}
```

this only works for onclicks not longClicks.  If you need Longclicks i think your gonig to have to loop through the table at runtime and find each textview and set the onLongClickListener programatically.  Please advise.